# Pipe is empty after passing its file descriptor to a subprocess which wrote to it

Tags: python, c++, unix, subprocess, pipe

The following Python codes creates a pipe with `os.pipe()` and passes its file descriptors to a subprocess via `pass_fds` of `subprocess.Popen()`. `stdout`, `stderr`, and the return code behave as expected. However, trying to read the pipe with `os.fdopen()` after the subprocess ends yields nothing; the program doesn't terminate because `read()` perpetually waits for something to be written to the pipe.

```
import subprocess as sp
import os

r, w = os.pipe()
p = sp.Popen(
    ["fd_test", str(w)],
    text=True,
    stdout=sp.PIPE,
    stderr=sp.PIPE,
    pass_fds=(r, w)
)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
print(stdout)
print(stderr)
print(p.returncode)

with os.fdopen(r, "r") as msg:
    print(msg.read())
```

The subprocess, `fd_test`, is a short program I wrote in C++ which writes "Hello, world!" to a given file descriptor:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2)
        return 1;

    int fd = std::stoi(std::string(argv[1]));
    std::string msg = "Hello, world!\n";

    if (write(fd, msg.c_str(), msg.size()) == -1) {
        std::fprintf(stderr, "Failed to write to '%d'\n", fd);
        return 1;
    }

    /*char* buf[512] = {0};
    if (read(fd - 1, buf, 512) == -1 {
        std::fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read from %d'\n", fd - 1);
        return 1;
    }
    std::printf("%s", buf);*/

    std::printf("Wrote message to %d\n", fd);
    std::fprintf(stderr, "No errors, hurray!\n");
}
```

The program reports no errors writing to the file descriptor. In fact, the commented out code can successfully read back what was just written, yet the parent Python process cannot.

How can I fix this? The only thing I could think of trying was `os.set_inheritable()` but it didn't help.